# I want to copy the value of input and textarea to clipboard

Tags: jquery, django, templates, copy

I have a question ^^;

I want to copy the input to the clipboard by pressing copy1 using js or jquery

I want to copy textarea to clipboard by pressing copy2

Thank you if you let me know how.

==============================================

I searched some code for this, but it felt difficult.

I applied this code

```js
$("#copy_code").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  document.execCommand('copy', false, document.getElementById('select-this').select());

  alert("copy is completed")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="" value="{{p.content1}}" size="40">
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm myinput" id="copy_code select-this">copy1</button>
```

ex)
https://codepen.io/fabean/pen/GprQJa

but error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):251)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (custom.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (custom.js:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id="copy_code select-this"` is incorrect. Guessing by your JS, you actually wanted the `input` to have `id="select-this"` and the `button` to have `id="copy_code"`.

```js
$("#copy_code").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  document.execCommand('copy', false, document.getElementById('select-this').select());

  alert("copy is completed")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="select-this" type="text" name="" value="{{p.content1}}" size="40">
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm myinput" id="copy_code">copy1</button>
```

Comment: I made a mistake in setting id

Thanks for letting me know.